# How to use SQLite with Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, mobile, swift

I am trying to create a SQLite database in Swift but not quite sure how to do so/start. I have never programmed in Objective C either, but I do have experience with SQLite in the Android system. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: compprogjava> What did you end up using?